# Dlink Search Hijack redirect

Tags: router, redirection, hijack

http://www1.dlinksearch.com/main etc.

Is hijack the right term, in any case, on my computer/cell phones , when online using Google; when doing searches or clicking on links randomly get taken to dlink search results page. seems to be no pattern, happens when website doesn't exist, but also for web pages I know are there.

Have Dlink server. Tried the "RESET" as suggested; seem to stop redirecting for a bit.
But now seems to have come back, if it was ever gone.

In forums I have read widely different possibilities. That this is a new feature that Dlink has incorporated in latest upgrade and need to opt out vs. this is malicious. 
Speculation is inevitable, but hopefully someone has one answer/solution.

No clue about tech terms, DNS all that stuff. Might someone be able to give me the nitty gritty.

Further details: Windows 7, typically use Goole to search, Dlink wirelss router hooked up to internet router, cell phones use wireless router

Can look up router name/type, etc. 
Meantime - help

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/google-public-dns-on-win7-and-winxp.html

Scroll down to the Windows 7 instructions. If your DNS settings are the problem this SHOULD fix it.

Comment: So I have done nothing as of yet, the redirect seems to be no longer happening, but other odds stuff happening e.g. battery icon gone, in systray battery option grayed out; dvd autolaunch no longer happens, can not play/launch dvd movies from dvd player, baffled

Comment: you might have a virus. try running Malwarebytes or Avast scans.